# CSS family greed height

Tags: html, css

some problem with CSS Horizontal Family Tree (https://codepen.io/P233/pen/Kzbsi/)
can see on screen
[screen off problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/por7Z.png)

If in a field of a cell some (3) lines that they creep one on another
how it can be fixed?

```
    <html>
<style type="text/css">
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #eee9dc;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #2e6ba7;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
    232332<br>
    wewewe<br>
    srer
    </span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label"><span>Entry-1</span></br>
    <span>232332</span></br>
    <span>wewewe</span></br>
    <span>srer</span></br></span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
    232332<br>
    wewewe<br>
    srer</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1<br>
    232332<br>
    wewewe<br>
    srer</span>
        <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try max-width also on .label class and give a try

Comment: may be max-height? but it not effected (

Comment: give max-height with overflow: auto; it works. But is that ok if you get scroll inside label

Comment: no changes
But with the addition in height, the joys increase downward, and the top is fixed